# "no implicit conversion of Symbol into String" carrierwave rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Being a newbie in R-O-R, I am trying to add file uploading capability in a web app. I am using rails 4, ruby 3.0 and trying to use carrierwave gem for file upload. I went through an example and that works fine. But when I implement the same code I am getting an issue and not able to figure out where exactly I am making a mistake.

Example I referred to learn http://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave

create view of web app:

```
<div class="well"> 
  <%= form_for [:admin, @firmware_version], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %> 
  <%= f.label :attachment %> 
  <%= f.file_field :attachment %> 
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %> 
<% end %> 
</div>
```

Created an uploaded "FirmwareUploader"

```
class FirmwareUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
       "/home/user1/filedownloadtrial"
  end
end
```

Model is as:

```
class FirmwareVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hw_supported, :upload_location, :version
  mount_uploader :attachment, FirmwareUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
end
```

My model did not have the column "attachment" so I created a migration for adding a column "attachment" as string. I created this while trying to fix the issue, but it didn't help.

Controller's create action

```
def create
@firmware_versions = FirmwareVersion.new(params.require(:firmware_version).permit(:attachment)) 

if @firmware_versions.save
  redirect_to firmware_versions_path, notice: "The firmware_versions has been uploaded."
else
  render "new"
end
```

end

So when I select the file to upload and "save" is clicked, I get the following error:

```
TypeError in Admin::FirmwareVersionsController#create
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
....
....
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   firmware_version
```

Below is the call stack:

```
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
app/controllers/admin/firmware_versions_controller.rb:50:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__852872005__process_action__698653545__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
```

I searched but couldn't figure out what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from controler.
    @firmware_versions=FirmwareVersion.new(params.require(:firmware_version).permit(:attachment))

I changed it to 
    @firmware_versions = FirmwareVersion.new
    @firmware_versions.attachmant = params[:firmware_version][:attachment]